# Parse error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, parsing, header

My site suddenly started displaying this error code:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in  in /home/kristaps/public_html/juta.skydrive.lv/wp-content/themes/mygrid2/**header.php** on **line 5**`

Could you please look up line 5 for mistake? **Thank you very much in advance!**

Here are first lines from header editor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo(''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''html_type''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''); ?> ;charset=<?php bloginfo(''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''charset''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''); ?>" />

<title><?php bloginfo(''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''name''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> &raquo; Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a typo error in the 5th line
The part:

```
content="<?php bloginfo('
```

The portion where it ends, there is semi-colon instead of double quotes

```
'''); ?> ;charset=<?php bloginfo
         ^
```

Just try correcting it and report back if there is any problem.